# Python: Remove entry in a nested list

Tags: python

I have a nested list that I would like to delete rows after it has finished with them. i tried using enumerating to pass in the index of the row to delete.

```
nlist = [['Chris', 'Davids', 21], ['Rob', 'Croft', 26]]

for i, v in enumerate(nlist):
   if v[0] == 'Chris':
       del v[i]
```

Comment: `if v[0] == 'Chris':`

Comment: `== 'chris'` will never be true because all your names start with a capital letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`== 'chris'` should be `== 'Chris':` because 'chris' will never be true because all your names start with a capital letter

This will remove the whole first sublist:

```
nlist = [['Chris', 'Davids', 21], ['Rob', 'Croft', 26]]

for i, v in enumerate(nlist):
   if v[0] == 'Chris':
       nlist.remove(nlist[i])

print nlist
```

Comment: That was a typo in the post. I edit the original when i realized. Thanks for your answer. Just what i was looking for.